# What DOS script command "gets" a value from the console?

Tags: batch-file, dos

This is very basic, and I am annoyed that I can't remember, but it has been a long time.

I want to write a MSDOS batch command script that gets a value from the console to use in the script.  I can't remember which command it is, and the reference I have relies upon one knowing the name of the command.  Which I don't remember.

Can someone unlock this issue for me?

OK, it isn't really DOS, it is a batch command file in Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

```
set /p name= your age?
```

Im not sure but. *name* is the variable assigned user input. *Your age?* is message displayed when asking for input.

Comment: "The /P switch was introduced in Windows 2000": http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php  So if this is truly DOS, it won't work.  If it's XP or Win7, it should work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, there really *wasn't* any effective way .

Here are a few (very ugly) workarounds, including "COPY CON":

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php

Here's a very simple menu system:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsMenu.php#Batch.Menu

Note: the syntax may or may not work depending on your DOS version.

Q:
Is this really "DOS" (as in MS-DOS), or a command prompt on a modern, Windows OS?

If the latter, you can do just about anything you want with Windows scripting or Powershell.